# How to change files owner/group(root) in cPanel?

Tags: magento, cpanel

I want to add address finder extension of Magento2 in cPanel. so I install via manual method and input in cPanel  terminal.

bin/magento module:enable AddressFinder_AddressFinder

but it is not install[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksKSk.png)
The reason is owner/group of public_htnl directory is "caterin1" and Migration directory is "root"
Note: caterin1 is as reseller or root user.